# Server side tick box selection using a Telerik radgrid in asp.net (C#)

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I'm trying to save my tickbox selection for a radgrid. I noticed Telerik had a tutorial on this as stated here: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-selecting-row-with-checkbox-server-side.html however this does not work for me and I think it's because I'm using advanced binding (i.e. OnNeedDataSource event). My radgrid looks like so:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="batchGrid" runat="server" 
AllowFilteringByColumn="True" AllowSorting="True" 
CellSpacing="0" GridLines="None" OnNeedDataSource="batchGrid_NeedDataSource"
EnableViewState="False" AutoGenerateColumns="True" OnColumnCreated="batchGrid_ColumnCreated"
OnExportCellFormatting="batchGrid_ExportCellFormatting">

    <ExportSettings ExportOnlyData="true" HideStructureColumns="true"  >
        <Excel Format="Html"/>
    </ExportSettings>

    <ClientSettings AllowColumnsReorder="True" EnablePostBackOnRowClick="false" > 
        <Selecting AllowRowSelect="false"/> 
        <Resizing AllowResizeToFit="true" />
    </ClientSettings>

    <MasterTableView  NoMasterRecordsText="No batch found containing this part, with the current filters">
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="CheckBoxTemplateColumn" AllowFiltering="false" Reorderable="false" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="MyCheckBox" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="ToggleRowSelection" AutoPostBack="true" />
                </ItemTemplate> 
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="headerChkbox" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="ToggleSelectedState" AutoPostBack="true" />
                </HeaderTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
        </Columns>
        <RowIndicatorColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter RowIndicator column" Visible="True">
            <HeaderStyle Width="20px" />
        </RowIndicatorColumn>
        <ExpandCollapseColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter ExpandColumn column" Visible="True">
            <HeaderStyle Width="20px" />
        </ExpandCollapseColumn>
        <EditFormSettings>
            <EditColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter EditCommandColumn column"></EditColumn>
        </EditFormSettings>
    </MasterTableView>

    <FilterMenu EnableImageSprites="False" ></FilterMenu>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

Currently ToggleRowSelection and ToggleSelectedState don't do anything, just declare a string that's not used and I put breakpoints on them so in debug mode I can tell when they're entered. However if I ever click a tick box in the radgrid, batchGrid_NeedDataSource is called before either which is really what I need to fix.

Sorry if this has been asked before, I had a search but people tended to either save the tick box selection client side or use simple data binding.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your exact code and got the calls to `ToggleRowSelection` and `ToggleSelectedState` in the code-behind to work by removing `EnableViewState="False"` from the RadGrid's definition.  Everything else can stay the same.

Comment: Yes I noticed this worked aswell, I was hoping for a work around because manually handling the view state would mean a design overhaul for my project. I suspect this may be the only solution though. I've noticed letting Telerik tools handle things by itself such as using Ajax panels, and simple data binding causes constraints on what you can do later on. Thankyou for your answer

Comment: OK cool, hope this helped.  If this answers your question, you should mark it as accepted.  If you then need help getting a workaround set, you should ask a new question.